# Synchronizing Website (DOM) on multiple devices

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, web, synchronization

I need to invent a method to synchronize multiple devices that are connected to a Website.
Lets say I have a Tablet and a Laptop and change some elements of the dom on the laptop. Then the
website on the Tablet should change accordingly.

At first I need a way to monitor the dom changes. I read a lot in forums and have also tried to work with browser-synch (https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync) but it does not monitor all events. However it may happen that the websites are not in synch.

I have also tried to use the new MutationServer techniques. But I am not sure how exactly to update the websites on the other devices:

In case a new node has been added to the DOM I first have to determine its position inside the tree; then send all the informations to the other clients (i guess via nodejs and socketio). The clients have to put the newly created node in the right position of their tree.

In case a node has been edited or removed I have to react on it as well...

So my question is: Do you have any ideas or literature to solve my problem?
I just need some good hints to start because I am not really sure which method leads me to the "best" solution. I want to invent an efficient solution as well. 
Sure, I could monitor the DOM by checking x times in a second whether changes occured. But this method is not really efficient especially not for mobile devices.

Hope you guys can help me and lead me to the right direction.

Best regards.

Comment: You mean the `DOM.addEventListener` events for you or is it something else?

Comment: Not sure whether this is the most efficient way. I need to monitor the complete DOM tree and detect ANY kind of changes.

Comment: is just a "DOM element"? Or is the whole page?

Comment: The whole page.. beginning from the <html> tag.
Browser-Sync is a tool that supports this features (not all). But I want to create a tool on my own and not analyzing and rewriting other programs,

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going and do not believe this is the best way (whatever you try to achieve). If you can tell what the reason for this is perhaps the simplest way.

Comment: The reason is my master thesis. I did not start it yet. Before I start it i am doing some research to exlude methods that are inefficient. 

I need to implement a mechanism on my own. So before I start I have to concrentrate on effective methods 1) to monitore the complete website 2) to send efficient messages to the clients. By efficient I mean that I want so send as less informations is possible but enough to perform all the changes...

Comment: If you want efficiency and transmit changes among customers, I think you should read my answer, the part that says: "From my point of view." Hope that helps something.

Answer (score 1):

> note: There is nothing ready and this is not so simple to do.

1. Capture all DOM maybe this will help you: [AcID DOM Inspector](http://adi.janmyler.com/)
2. Capture "event Listeners" use [Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)

Avoid capture frames (or use them) because security issues (cross-origin) may occur.

In my view it is not necessary to capture the entire document, it would only be necessary to capture inserts the "BODY" and "HEAD"

And avoid complex structures, perhaps the events (eventslistiners) need not be captured, only you would need to have a library that adds already existing events. Unless the events are created by customers, in which case you will have to capture them.

To transmit them you have to use Ajax and shared with DataBase (SQLServer, Mysql, MongoDB, etc).

### From my point of view:

**If you want to create is an application just to share data**, for example someone posted a "new photo" or a "new comment", would be better to make the transmission of which was inserted in the "database" for "JSON" and clients read the "JSON" your main "javascript library" would dynamically generate the contents.

Thus would transmit much less making things faster and easier to implement process.

Comment: Thank you. No I do not need to share data at all. I really need synchronization on multiple devices each time the client dom changes. I'll take a look at the links you provided and in case of questions i will post them here.

Comment: If you can tell what you're really trying to achieve (do not say of functionality), all this work is perhaps not necessary. I still believe that only transmit data and your "lib" (client-side) generate the "DOM elements" and "events". I really want to help him.